# how to load balance between IBMMQmanager via mq-client in application

Tags: java, apache-camel, ibm-mq

I have multiple IBMMQQueueManager on which i have to loadbalance and connect to the queues hosted on queuemanager. I have HA configuration for QueueManager but I don't see and example for that. CAn someone help me understand this configuration so that I can easily load balance between queuemanager from client application.

Also It would be great if someone could help me with this configuration on camel.

Comment: If you can configure Camel to use a MQ Client Channel Definition Table, you could use a queue manager group to specify multiple entries and and when you conned MQ will pick one, or you could front end your queue managers with a IP load balancer like a F5 LTM device.  There are some other questions under the [ibm-mq] tag which discuss both.

Comment: Thanks, Looks promising, do you have any example where i can reference?

Comment: Type in searches in the search box at the top, some suggested searches are "[ibm-mq] f5" or "[ibm-mq] CCDT" or "[ibm-mq] load balance"